# Is there any specific way how I can access the data residing inside my Firestore database via Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my Environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    firebase: {
      projectId: 'project-id',
      appId: 'app-ID',
      databaseURL: 'db-url',
      storageBucket: 'bucket-name',
      locationId: 'zone-region',
      apiKey: 'api-key',
      authDomain: 'auth-domain',
      messagingSenderId: 'senderId',
      measurementId: 'measurement-id',
    }
  };
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
      AngularFirestoreModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
export class AppModule { }
```

I have initialized the firebase admin via app.module.ts but I am not sure how to access the firestore database hereafter

What I want to achieve is to be able to access the data inside my Firestore database using API via app.component.ts, please suggest

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on working with Firestore in Angular, but it's hard to tell what you tried or what you're having problems with.  I suggest starting with the docs or some tutorial, then show what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  I don't think anyone can write a helpful tutorial for you here since we don't really know what you're working with.